# Value is 20,10000, error appeared

Tags: c, integer

To test two 32-bit integers, m whose factorial is m! can be divisible by n. If it can, the function `divides()` returns 1, otherwise 0.
As the codes below, the problem is when m = 2010000, error happened. Could you please explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long factorial(long n){
    if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) return 1;
    else{
    return (n * factorial(n-1));
    }        
}
int divides (long n,long m)
{
    long facN;
    printf("n=%ld ",n);
    facN = factorial(n);
    if(m != 0){
    if(facN == 1) return 0;
        else{
            if(facN % m == 0) return 1;
            else if((facN % m) != 0)return 0;
        }
   }
   else if(m == 0) return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", divides(2000000,1));
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Could you provide it in your question? Thanks!

Comment: calling factorial(2000000) will not end well

Comment: You're trying to compute 2 million factorial???????

Comment: The function *devides* return nothing and the test line *`printf("n=%d",n)`* cannot output.

Comment: For reference, 

 5! = 120,
 10! = 3628800,
 15! = 1.3076744e+12, and
 20! = 2.432902e+18...

How big do you think 2000000! will be?

Comment: I recommend a pause in your mathematics classes and a bit more focus on your computer science classes.

Comment: @CareyGregory I recommend the exact opposite. Bringing this task down into a computable level requires for more maths proficiency than it does for CS proficiency.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin You make a good point, but CS proficiency would have told the OP immediately that his solution was doomed to failure and not to waste further time on that avenue.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yeah, that's also a really good point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute the factorial with the modulus already taken into account. Using the following identity:

```
(a * b) % n = ((a % n) * (b % n)) % n
```

we can compute the factorial as:

```
m! % n = (((((1 % n) * 2) % n) * 3) % n) ...) % n
```

Comment: @user3467247 Cool. Usual practice is to hit the little checkmark next to the answer you like.

Comment: @U2EF1 Good luck with that. SO has changed moderation criteria such that there's absolutely no reason for "help vampires" to bother accepting answers.

Answer (score 2):

A 32-bit integer can only store factorials from 0 to 12.

```
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12
479001600
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13
6227020800
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that 69! is of the order of 10^98 you are probably looking at value overflows but you might also be looking at running out of memory/stack as you will be nesting 2 million deep in your recursion.

Also your check `if((facN % m) != 0)` is redundant as it is called in the `else` to `if(facN % m == 0)`

Comment: If 69!, the program runs properly.

Comment: The size of 69! is from my memory as the older calculators will not display 70! as it is > 9e99.

Answer (score 0):

If your cause is all about finding out whether if `m!` for an `m` is divisible by an `n`, do not calculate the factorial at all.

Rather split `n` to its factors, check if there are enough many of those inside the numbers ranging from `1` to `m`, inclusive.

For example; for `m = 7` and `n = 28`, the process should be like the following:

```
n % 2 == 0 ? yes
n /= 2
2 * 1 <= m ? yes

n % 2 == 0 still? yes
n /= 2
2 * 2 <= m ? yes

n % 2 == 0 still? no

n % 3 == 0 ? no

...

n % 7 == 0 ? yes
n /= 7
7 <= m ? yes

n reached 1, return 1
```

Something like this. If you cannot manage to write this, then you probably shouldn't be dealing with that question yet. Still, if you want, leave a comment, I can edit my answer to include a working code.

I am adding a working example, using the logic above to display whether `n` is a divisor of `m!`, just to assure you that this thing does indeed work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// this function basically compares the powers of the
// prime divisors of factee and divisor
// ... returns 1 if the powers in divisor are
// ... less than or equal to the powers in factee
// ... returns 0 otherwise
int divides( long factee, long divisor ){

    int amount;

    for ( int i = 2; i <= factee; i++ ){

        if ( divisor % i )
            continue;

        amount = 0;
        int copy = factee;
        while ( copy ){
            copy /= i;
            amount += copy;
        }

        while ( divisor % i == 0 ){
            if ( !amount )
                return 0;
            amount--;
            divisor /= i;
        }

        if ( divisor == 1 )
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main( )
{
    printf( "%d", divides( 20, 10000 ) );

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

`amount` variable calculates the amount of `i` there are inside the `m!`. In the `while` loop in which it gets calculated, with the first cycle, the amount of `i`s are added, then with the second cycle, the amount of `i * i`s are added, and so on, until there aren't any.

For example, with `m = 5` and `i = 2`, `m / 2` is `2`, which is the amount of occurrence of the factor `2` inside the `5!`. Then `m / 2 / 2`, which is `1`, is the amount of occurrence of the factor `2 * 2 == 4` inside the `5!`. Then `m / 2 / 2 == 0` is the count for `2 * 2 * 2 == 8`, which causes the loop to end due to the `0` encounter.

### *Edit*

I fixed something important in the code, removed the outermost `while` which was there for nothing, something I had put as I started and apparently forgot to remove, causing potential infinite-loops. Here I also made an improved version of the function that generally runs faster than the one above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// this function basically compares the powers of the
// prime divisors of factee and divisor
// ... returns 1 if the powers in divisor are
// ... less than or equal to the powers in factee
// ... returns 0 otherwise
int divides( long factee, long divisor ){

    int amount;

    if ( divisor % 2 == 0 ){
        amount = 0;
        int copy = factee;

        while ( divisor % 2 == 0 ){
            if ( !amount ){
                copy /= 2;
                if ( !copy )
                    return 0;
                amount += copy;
            }
            amount--;
            divisor /= 2;
        }

        if ( divisor == 1 )
            return 1;
    }

    for ( int i = 3; i <= factee; i += 2 ){

        if ( divisor % i )
            continue;

        amount = 0;
        int copy = factee;

        while ( divisor % i == 0 ){
            if ( !amount ){
                copy /= i;
                if ( !copy )
                    return 0;
                amount += copy;
            }
            amount--;
            divisor /= i;
        }

        if ( divisor == 1 )
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main( ) {
    printf( "%d", divides( 34534564, 345673455 ) );
    //printf( "%d", divides( 20, 10000 ) );

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the explantion of quesion is incorrect, in fact, I mean to test,if m! can be devisible or not, not just the plain m

Comment: @user3467247 The explanation is all good, and I didn't misunderstand anything. Think of it like this: **(1)** The factors of `m!` are all the integers `1, 2, 3, ..., m` **(2)** A number which can divide `m!` should consist of those factors of `m!`

Comment: @ThoApplsin If m = 20, n=10000, m has been defined double, but it still work well, could you figure out that?

Comment: @user3467247 Well, the example I gave does not cover the whole algorithm; for example, you'd have to count the other 2 inside the 4 for `m = 4` and `n = 8`. For your m and n, however, the example run I gave is all enough: `2 * 1 --> 5000` then `2 * 2 --> 2500` ... `2 * 4 --> 625` and they all are `<= 20`. Then `5 *` 1, 2, 3 and 4 reduces `n` to 125, 25, 5 then 1; all `5 *`s being `<= 20` again. If there still is something unclear, just tell me how I may help, even maybe to just lay down a code doing this stuff...

Comment: @ThoApplsin Your explaintion is very useful for me and thanks for your code.But it runs much longer time, I`m sorry to say that it is not the best algorithm but it`s really much better than mine. Anyway,thanks a lot.;)

Comment: @user3467247 Could you tell me under which circumstances it got slow, so that I may improve it accordingly?

Comment: @user3467247 Okay, there used to be a bug in the code, causing infinite-loops with some inputs. It might be that you had one of those... Other than that, I also have put down another one which runs generally like half of what the other one does.

Answer (score -1):

long can support a value in the range of -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647, here 2000000! is out of the range of long, that is why it is showing error.